# RFC 1123 Date Representation in Python?

Tags: python, http, datetime

Is there a fairly easy way to convert a datetime object into an RFC 1123 (HTTP/1.1) date/time string, i.e. a string with the format

```
Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
```

Using `strftime` does not work, since the strings are locale-dependant. Do I have to build the string by hand?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use wsgiref.handlers.format_date_time from the stdlib which does not rely on locale settings

```
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

now = datetime.now()
stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())
print format_date_time(stamp) #--> Wed, 22 Oct 2008 10:52:40 GMT
```

You can use email.utils.formatdate from the stdlib which does not rely on locale settings

```
from email.utils import formatdate
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

now = datetime.now()
stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())
print formatdate(
    timeval     = stamp,
    localtime   = False,
    usegmt      = True
) #--> Wed, 22 Oct 2008 10:55:46 GMT
```

If you can set the locale process wide then you can do:

```
import locale, datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'en_US')
datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
```

If you don't want to set the locale process wide you could use [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) [date formating](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/dates.html)

```
from datetime import datetime
from babel.dates import format_datetime

now = datetime.utcnow()
format = 'EEE, dd LLL yyyy hh:mm:ss'
print format_datetime(now, format, locale='en') + ' GMT'
```

A manual way to format it which is identical with wsgiref.handlers.format_date_time is:

```
def httpdate(dt):
    """Return a string representation of a date according to RFC 1123
    (HTTP/1.1).

    The supplied date must be in UTC.

    """
    weekday = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"][dt.weekday()]
    month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
             "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][dt.month - 1]
    return "%s, %02d %s %04d %02d:%02d:%02d GMT" % (weekday, dt.day, month,
        dt.year, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second)
```

Comment: This solution won't work for the reason outlined in the question: stftime is locale-dependant.

Comment: that's why you ocale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'en_US')

Comment: And that's why SO needs an indicator of when answers were edited.

Comment: @Sebastian: which of the many good solutions did you select as "best"?

Comment: They are all good solutions, depending on what you want to achieve. For example, the outside dependecies can be used when you are already using that dependency. wsgiref can be used with Python 2.5+, and the manual solution is the fall-back case.

Comment: @Florian because some formatting string, %a, %b are determined by your locale settings

Comment: Why not just `stamp = time.time()` instead of `now = datetime.now();
stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())` ?

Comment: `email.utils.formatdate` is also in standard lib of Python3. I prefer this solution :)

Comment: Just a minor suggestion: it probably should be `en_US.UTF-8` instead of `en_US` for setting the locale.

Comment: Caution: Pay attention to time zones. `time.mktime()` [assumes the time given is local](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime). Use `calendar.timegm()` for UTC.

Comment: `email.utils.formatdate` also has a corresponding `email.utils.parsedate`

Comment: You can modify that function to take in a time.gmtime() object, whose relevant attributes are `tm_wday`, `tm_mon`, `tm_mday`, `tm_year`, `tm_hour`, `tm_min`, `tm_sec`.

Answer (score 58):

You can use the formatdate() function from the Python standard email module:

```
from email.utils import formatdate
print formatdate(timeval=None, localtime=False, usegmt=True)
```

Gives the current time in the desired format:

```
Wed, 22 Oct 2008 10:32:33 GMT
```

In fact, this function does it "by hand" without using strftime()

Comment: I love that you can do this as a one-liner in a subshell. `curl -X POST -H "$(python3 -c 'from email.utils import formatdate; print(formatdate(timeval=None, localtime=False, usegmt=True))')" https://httpbin.org/POST`.

Comment: @dragon788 I guess in a shell you'd rather use the `date` command, as in `LANG=C date -u +"%a, %d %B %Y %T GMT"`  You may not be able to rely in python3 being installed.

Comment: As the question was specifically for a `datetime` you need `format_datetime`.

Comment: From the shell I think you can just do `date -Ru`

Answer (score 20):

If anybody reading this is working on a **Django** project, Django provides a function [`django.utils.http.http_date(epoch_seconds)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.http_date).

```
from django.utils.http import http_date

some_datetime = some_object.last_update
response['Last-Modified'] = http_date(some_datetime.timestamp())
```

This function uses [`email.utils.formatdate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.formatdate), this is equivalent to:

```
from email.utils import formatdate

response['Last-Modified'] = formatdate(some_datetime.timestamp(), usegmt=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set LC_TIME to force stftime() to use a specific locale:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'en_US')
'en_US'
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime(locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT))
'Wed 22 Oct 2008 06:05:39 AM '
```

Comment: Well, setting (and resetting) locale.LC_TIME works, of course, but this has disadvantages, like most likely not being thread-safe, and depending on the catalog of string translations. Also, locale.D_T_FMT does not return the right format with LC_TIME set to en_US.

Comment: locale.D_T_FMT was merely an example. You can pass any format you like to strftime().

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is a manual function to format it:

```
def httpdate(dt):
    """Return a string representation of a date according to RFC 1123
    (HTTP/1.1).

    The supplied date must be in UTC.

    """
    weekday = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"][dt.weekday()]
    month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
             "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][dt.month - 1]
    return "%s, %02d %s %04d %02d:%02d:%02d GMT" % (weekday, dt.day, month,
        dt.year, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second)
```