# Rfc 1123 in python

Tags: python, time, dst

Just want to use 'datetime' or 'time' modules. I based the following code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225086/rfc-1123-date-representation-in-python) question:

```
import time

def rfc1123 (gmt):
    weekday = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"][gmt.tm_wday]

    month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][gmt.tm_mon]

    return "%s, %02d %s %04d %02d:%02d:%02d GMT" % (weekday, gmt.tm_mday, month, gmt.tm_year, gmt.tm_hour, gmt.tm_min, gmt.tm_sec)

print (rfc1123 (time.gmtime ()))
```

Is something wrong ? I'm really worried about the DST.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do it :

```
from time import strftime, gmtime
strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
```

See exemple in python [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Comment: No funciona siempre, depende del "locale" del sistema operativo.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bit of flexibility around using `datetime` or `time`, an even easier way to do it is to use [email.utils.formatdate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.formatdate). See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/225177/1450294) for more information.