# Archetypes locale aware DateTime field

Tags: plone

When saving a Spanish date string value into an Archetypes DateTimeField, the field ends up with a None value.  I've read through the DateTimeField code and there is no locale code there at all.  I am sure that this, like most things, has already been done somewhere in Plone, and I would like to know where, please.

If it hasn't yet been done, then I would appreciate any comments you might have about my plan.  I have collected some information from Google and SO, and this is what I came up with:

1) I will subclass the Archetypes/Field.py/DateTimeField() in my own source.

2) I will use `@@plone_portal_state/language()` to get the current language code.

3) Then set locale, using `locale.setlocale(local.LC_TIME, LANG_CODE)`.

4) I will convert the string value to a python `datetime` object.

5) I will use `dt2DT` to convert the value to zope DateTime.

6) I will then write the value.

This is a silly plan, but it is what I know, and I would love some clues.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/collective/plone.app.event and http://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar/ to see how far that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, but what I want is to display local time such as  **Jan 01, 2012** in French in Spanish locale, however doing research I found out that **locale.setlocale** is not thread safe on most of the systems, so it's not a good idea to keep setting/unsetting it because it will probably set that particular locale for everyone using the site.

You still can install required locales for the selected languages, in Debian you can do this with:

***#aptitude install locales***

then

***#dpkg-reconfigure locales***

Select all the locale languages you need and the system would have them. There should be a way of translating month name formats, but I haven't found it yet.

Sources:

Plone discussion  -- http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Plone-strftime-and-locales-question-td6602394.html

Python locale documentation page, scroll down to locale.setlocale -- http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html

**EDIT**: Also instead of locale.setlocale you might want to use babel package, as it appears to be thread-safe, I'm currently investigating that possibility for my own project.

Stack Overflow discussion -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/225106/86294

Babel on Pypi -- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Babel